# Jenkins Salesforce CI server setup

Tags: ant, migration-tool, release, continuous-integration, jenkins

I have a simple doubt and wanted to get community perspective.
I have set up Jenkins for all my Salesforce deployments with Force.com Migration tool.

Now it works properly on my local machine without issues.

Question - What is the easiest way to set up a server which can help me test out my Jenkins jobs? Is there any free to use server available which can be used?

Comment: I have serious doubts if this question is salesforce related. You can try to get free EC2 amazon instance of course, but that is free only for limited time

Comment: @kurunve This seems very relevant to Salesforce to me. Trailhead even has modules that cover CI. Jenkins is mentioned as one of the component that can be implemented as part of a CI solution. The difficulty with this question is what constitutes "easiest". It's subject to opinion. If rephrased to "what are my options?", then he has a valid question.

Comment: @crmprogdev it seems that my comment did not describe my thoughts properly.  As far as I understand question, it is not about configuring SF deployment with Jenkins, it is about picking vps to install Jenkins there. IMO, if there are any questions about **picking** server, then they can be answered by articles like this (f.e. [here]http://bfy.tw/9ioR ). If there are issues with Jenkins config - SO [Jenkins tag](http://bit.ly/2jk6uHJ). And in case if there are issues with  SF connection via Jenkins - then SFSE.  Jenkins is standalone tool, and there are a lot of hosting info about it over web.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have number of options here

**1.Using EC2**

EC2 is from amazon and have seen number of enterprises using EC2

**2.Using Google Cloud Containers**

https://cloud.google.com/container-engine/

**3.Cloudbees**

https://www.cloudbees.com/products/jenkins-cloud